# how to programmatically set a group audience

Tags: 7, forms, organic-groups

I am trying to programmatically add the group audience widget to a custom form (without using OG field setting) and set it to a default value.

Would anyone know of a way to do so?

---

Well after one week of investigation i still haven t find an answer. I gotta say i am really dispointed by OG module, the documentation is so poor and the maintainer doesn't really help improving this. A real shame such a module isn't more documented

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First in your .install when creating your content type, add:

```
og_create_field(OG_AUDIENCE_FIELD, 'node', 'bundle_name_of_your_content_type');
```

Then when you need to assign a fresh new content of your content type to an existing group, you can do it in two ways:

1) Found it http://drupal.org/node/1249396#comment-4885442 and thanks to tenken

```
$node = node_load($nid);  
$values = array(  
  'entity type' => 'node',  
  'entity' => $node, 
  'state' => OG_STATE_ACTIVE);
og_group($gid, $values);
node_save($node);
```

2) Maybe less sexy

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$node->group_audience['und'][0] = array(
  'gid' => $gid, 
  'state' => OG_STATE_ACTIVE, 
  'created' => mktime());
node_save($node);
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks, i ended up not using OG at all for this project but that might be useful for someone

Comment: the function called,but didn't work,when runs,it still no member of that group.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Drupal 6, there is an API function named [og_form_add_og_audience()](http://drupalcode.org/project/og.git/blob/fd18b9ca812bf53542b2b9b3f9f999189bd390ac:/og.module#l1822) that you can leverage to add the audience widget to your custom form.  It is important to note that you will probably have to process the data yourself through a custom submit handler.

Comment: Thanks Chris, i am actually using Drupal 7 but i ll look into that.

Comment: Ah, then that API function doesn't exist in 7.  Bad assumption on my part :-)

Comment: I am trying to add a default audience field . How can I achieve that in drupal 6 using og_form_add_og_audience() Please help